# ATI move the unity bar to another screen using binary driver

Tags: unity, ati, 12.04

I must say, I'm really pleased with the 12.04 performance.  The only real issue I had is that I needed a custom screen orientation and the binary driver had no way to move the unity launcher, as far as I could tell.

I found a solution, so I'm asking the question.  This way more people can benefit from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, xrandr shows 3 displays.  The issue isn't with unity not moving the bar.  The issue is that I couldn't find a way in the amd binary driver gui to set the primary.
[image]
So we check for our active displays(in xrandr).  I see DFP 1, 3, and 4 are active.
Let's see 1:
[image]
Not how I want it.  Let's try 3:
[image]
Initially I thought I wanted it all the way on the left, but I think I like this the most.  We'll see.  Just to be thorough, let's take a look at 4:
[image]
And there you have it.  Put the unity bar on whatever screen you want with the ATI binary driver.

If you want this to hold through reboot, you need to add it to your start-up tasks.
If you want it to hold through sleep, you need to add a task to 99video